# Error after login to Magento on core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php on line 437

Tags: magento, authentication, backend

None of out programmers has changed anything to the code, but out of nothing now, when a user tries to login on the backend, we have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in
>   /home/r1tech/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php on
>   line 437

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this for the occasional googler with this issue:

We had this problem today, after we had tested different caching mechanisms for Magento. In the process, the file cache directory was somehow corrupted or otherwise made unusable. If you're not keen on reuploading the entire thing as Beto Frega suggests, you should be able to solve it by removing (or renaming) the var/cache (in the Magento webroot, not the server itself!!) directory and creating a new one, which you then obviously give write permissions to.

This solved the issue for us -- and incidentally also some performance issues in the backend, due to the sheer size of the old cache dir.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real Magento problem.

Somehow the files got corrupted. I re-uploaded everything and now it works just fine.